# Using Bootstrap: How to add a class when object is visible-xs visible-sm?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Ive been trying to find a solution to this problem. I have not been able to find any answers online. And unfortunately my javascript skills are not too good. I understand the basic concept of how to do this, the only problem I have is how to call that input and only when its in the visible modes.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 visible-xs visible-sm">
       <label for="date">Desired Date:</label>
       <input name="date" type="date" id="mobiledateinput">
</div>
```

I know this needs to be solved with javascript somehow. Heres as close as i could get

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("mobiledateinput, visible-xs").each( function () {
                $(this).addClass('validate-required');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Ok none of these answers are addressing the issue. Perhaps I didnt do a good job explaining myself. Basically I have these inputs on the html page. But when the form is submitted using desktop, it still attempts to verify the mobile only inputs, because all of these issues are just adding the validate-required class on page load. I need to figure out a way to only add this class when the input becomes visible. So perhaps there is a way to select the input, make a requiredment of it being visible, before adding the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries which is a CSS technique.

For example;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

I mean you can change class proporties.

visible-xs breakpoint is (max-width: 768px). You can find the all breakpoints in bootstrap website.

Comment: Ok none of these answers are addressing the issue. Perhaps I didnt do a good job explaining myself. Basically I have these inputs on the html page. But when the form is submitted using desktop, it still attempts to verify the mobile only inputs, because all of these issues are just adding the validate-required class on page load. I need to figure out a way to only add this class when the input becomes visible. So perhaps there is a way to select the input, make a requiredment of it being visible, before adding the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors should be

```
$(".mobiledateinput, .visible-xs")
```

If you don't have the period in front, jQuery doesn't know you are refering to a CSS class.

Comment: Ok none of these answers are addressing the issue. Perhaps I didnt do a good job explaining myself. Basically I have these inputs on the html page. But when the form is submitted using desktop, it still attempts to verify the mobile only inputs, because all of these issues are just adding the validate-required class on page load. I need to figure out a way to only add this class when the input becomes visible. So perhaps there is a way to select the input, make a requiredment of it being visible, before adding the class.

Comment: Remove the comma so you have $(".mobiledata.visible-xs")

Answer (score 0):

visible-sm classes, it add by bootstrap and the action will make when it be visible so it doesn't matter to pay attention to [ visible-xs visible-sm ]
so focus on the event of the input so to add class validate-required to all input with #mobiledateinput it will be....

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#mobiledateinput").each( function () {
                 var $this  = $(this) //to cash this object in the var $this
                 $this.addClass('validate-required');
        });

  });
```

I recommend using the class .mobiledateinput instead of ID because ID must be for one element in the page.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work. It just does the same thing as me adding the validate required class manually. Which Is the issue because if the form is submitted on desktop it still tries to verify these hidden inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a class `medium-css` and define the css like this

```
 /* only use this class for screens >= md */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* your Styles */
    .medium-css{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

or since you are using bootstrap `d-none` will help you

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block">
  This element is hidden on small screens, but displayed on md screens and larger.
</div>
```